# Missing check name

Tags: consul

Using the consul http api I am getting `Missing check name` in the response body when posting to the API. I've read the docs etc but can't find the problem. Anyone have any idea?

I am posting the below to http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/check/register

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "component",
    "tags": [
      "aws_instance_id"
    ],
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 80,
    "enable_tag_override": false,
    "node": "consulserver",
    "id": "test",
    "check": {
      "id": "health",
      "name": "HTTP API",
      "http": "http://localhost/health",
      "tls_skip_verify": false,
      "method": "GET",
      "interval": "10s",
      "timeout": "1s"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json was incorect, it should have been

```
{
    "name": "component",
    "tags": [
      "aws_instance_id"
    ],
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 80,
    "enable_tag_override": false,
    "node": "consulserver",
    "id": "test",
    "check": {
      "id": "health",
      "name": "HTTP API",
      "http": "http://localhost/health",
      "tls_skip_verify": false,
      "method": "GET",
      "interval": "10s",
      "timeout": "1s"
    }
  }
```